# Why does dairy-free ice cream get so hard?

Tags: dairy-substitutes

The first time I tried storebought dairy-free ice cream I could barely even wedge a scoop into it after taking it out of the freezer because it was so hard. I had never had that problem in the past with ice cream or frozen dessert. So now when I want to serve vegan ice cream I make sure to put it in the fridge for half an hour before serving it.

Have other people noticed this too, or am I remembering incorrectly? If dairy-free ice cream really is harder than the dairy kind, what is the cause of that?

Comment: hmm... I don't remember dairy ice cream being any softer than the various types of non-dairy ice cream I've tried... my parents (vegetarians with increasing dairy-replacing tendencies) haven't commented on this either. Specific ingredients? Different freezer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst I cannot be certain without knowing the brands of the two ice creams you are comparing, most vegan ice cream is lower in fat than non vegan ice cream.

A higher fat content makes ice cream more malleable at freezing temperatures as the fat has a lower freezing point than water.